# undefined method `columns_hash'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have used `shoulda_matchers` in my `specs`. For this test

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:role_id) }
```

I get this error:

```
Expected errors to include "has already been taken" when name is set to "arbitrary_string", got errors: ["name is already taken (\"arbitrary_string\")"]
```

When I change the test to:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).scoped_to(:role_id).with_message('is already taken') }
```

I am getting this error:

```
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `columns_hash' for Activity:Class
```

My model has only one field - `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mongoid` Models do not have a `columns_hash` class method and `shoulda-matchers` use this method.

The corresponding method in `mongoid` is `columns`

I was able to solve this issue by replacing the gems `shoulda` and `shoulda-matchers` with `mongoid-rspec`.

Comment: Any idea of what to do if you have a rails project using both and ActiveRecord and Mongoid?